# problem with ubuntu 11.04 server while installing windows virtual machine on it

Tags: server, windows, virtualization

*I have installed windows virtual machine on ubuntu 11.04 server.For every boot, windows VM asks for OS CD in server but the ubuntu desktop VM's reboots properly.

how can i resolve this problem? i need windows VM to boot properly without asking for OS CD?*

Answer (score 0):

Issue the following command

```
VBoxManage storageattach <vmname> --storagectl "IDE Controller" --device 0 --port 2 --type dvddrive --medium empty
```

or You can change the boot order first so that won't be a problem any more (set the hdd first, then the CD).

Comment: already my first boot order is on hdd only. Can you make it clear ??

Comment: remove the cd from boot order

Comment: am not using virtualbox.i have used gateways for virtualization. This problem does not occurs with ubuntu or fedora virtual machines.

Comment: can you give a link to your virtualization platform or software? I advise you to detach your cd from virtual machine (or dismount it)